# Why does the Visual Studio debugger not show the state machine code generated by the await keyword?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-2015

When I set a break-point into the body of a method that I am awaiting, the Visual Studio debugger shows a call stack that does not have any of the C# compiler generated code.

Please look at the picture below, which shows my simple `async` method and the call stack.

[image]

Notice that there is no call to the `MoveNext` or to initialize the state machine object or to the `TaskAwaiter<TResult>` or the `AsyncTaskOfTMethodBuilder` in the call stack.

Why is that so? Like there is in IL Spy, is there some setting in Visual Studio that I can toggle to have it show the state machine code in the call stack and in the editor while a debugging session is in progress?

I remembered suddenly that there is a `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` on the re-written button click handler code that instantiates the state machine. But I am not sure if that is the reason it is hidden from the debugger. Shouldn't this one just grey out the stack frame of the compiler generated methods in the call stack?

Isn't `DebuggerHiddenAttribute` the one that makes the code invisible to the debugger?

Comment: Your breakpoint is inside a task running on another thread, why should there be evidence of the callstack that *created* that thread? Did you check the separate thread window you can get in the debugger? I don't remember the name though but there is a window/pane you can open that shows the state of all threads in the program.

Comment: The problem, however, is that the button click event handler method is finished, temporarily. It has returned, this likely happened in the first milliseconds during the spinup of the extra thread which means that not only will the call stack of the thread running the task not show the button event handler, the method you're looking for has most likely already returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things to note here.

First of all, you have 2 threads in play:

1. The main thread, running the message pump for and owning the window that has the button in it
2. The thread that is running the task

The call stack inside one thread will in no way reflect what the thread that created it is currently doing.

At most, you would see the two threads and their callstack if you inspect the debugger pane that can show all the threads and their callstacks in the debugger.

However, this would only show the button event handler if the thread that executed this method was still in the method at the time the debugger hit your breakpoint. This is most likely not true due to the overhead of spinning up a new thread.

The reason for this is that `async/await` *returns* from the `async` method when it hits an `await`. By the time the separate thread had started executing your delegate, the button event handler method has most likely returned.

Even if you manually spun up a thread for your delegate and joined (waited for) that thread, you wouldn't see this in the *callstack*, but you should definitely see it in that other debugger pane for threads and their callstacks.

Comment: Oh yes. My bad. Thank you.